# 'Enable Notes' strange behaviour

Tags: attachment, notes, contentnote

When in Notes Settings 'Enable Notes', there are some strange situation.

1. They stop appear like Note records, and i don't know what object they represent now.
2. And, logically, they don't appear in 'Notes and attachments' related list.

Maybe i missed something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*In short*

1. They are not under `Note`, but instead `ContentNote`
2. `Notes and attachments` are for attachments and the "old" note records. Enhanced notes have their own related list (called "Notes").

---

*Longer form*

There's the [Considerations for Setting up Notes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.notes_considerations.htm&type=5) where below point is taken from the doc and answers your 2nd question:

> To set up Notes, add the **Notes related list** to all relevant page layouts and enable Notes.

This [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000337292&type=1&mode=1) also mentions the same about the "new" notes being managed in its own related list while the "legacy" notes being in the "notes & attachments" related list.

> Add the Notes Related List to Page Layouts while continuing to maintain the 'Notes & Attachments' related list on layouts to allow users to view and reference legacy notes added to records prior to enabling enhanced notes.

> In Lightning, the 'New Note' button is not available in the 'Notes & Attachments' related list. Users may only create enhanced notes via the 'New' button in the Notes related list.

Now, the reason for the need to switch related lists is due to, as you noted, the fact they're stored in a different manner. They no longer are within the [Note](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_note.htm) object.

"Enhanced Notes" are stored under [ContentNote](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm).

> Represents a note created with the enhanced note taking tool, released in Winter ‘16. This object is available in API version 32.0 and later.

To query, you can work directly against it

```
SELECT Id FROM ContentNote
```

However, it's important to spot this in the documentation

> ContentNote is built on ContentVersion, and so it has many of the same usages.

This allows you to actually query against [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm), which may have more information, using the `SNOTE` value for the `FileType` field.

```
SELECT Id FROM ContentVersion WHERE FileType = 'SNOTE
```